# Animation Issue on Unity 3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I made an 2D animation on Photoshop and I'm building 2D interactive novel for Android. I added 16 images to my scene and named it Myanimation. I need to play this animation after 10 secs from beginning. So I need to set Legacy on from Myanimation's debug menu. But when I click Legacy's box Myanimation's size in "Pptr Curve Mapping" changing to 0. And my animation doesn't play. (I think the problem is this. Coz If I try working with only 1 image and build moving animation it works.)

Anyway I am adding Animation (Add component-> Miscalleneous -> Animation) and adding Myanimation in it. And build a script like that

```js
function Start() {
    Invoke("Ersakonus", 1);
}

function Ersakonus() {
    animation.Play("Myanimation");
}
```

But when I play the game (Novel) it doesn't work. I need this coz I need to let other character's animations one by one while they are talking with Invoke.

Can you plase tell me how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Let try Animation.CrossFade

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.CrossFade.html
```

And then check your animation component have animation named or something but If u want Novel unity game take a look.

```
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/9416
```